# “Which country [starts / is started] with the letter ‘M’?”

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

Which one is correct?

> Which country is started with the letter ‘M’?
>
> Which country starts with the letter ‘M’?

If both are correct what is the difference between them?

Comment: "... starts with..."

Comment: could you explain it more please?but my teacher said that it's a kind of passive sentence!

Comment: Your first variant is not idiomatic. "A country beginning with B' etc _are_ idiomatic, at least in informal registers, and are shortened forms, modified to retain grammaticality if not semantic logic, of 'a country whose name begins with B' etc. So the answer depends (as is often the case) on how you are defining 'correct'. I'd never use your first variant, as it sounds weird. // As for the claim that a passive is / must be involved, this is wrong. 'The car started' is every bit as grammatical as 'the car was started'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the following are correct: "Which country's name starts with the letter 'M'?" or "Which country has a name that starts with the letter 'M'?"

Comment: but we have that one in one of original Oxford English book!"which US state.....................white letter H?(start)